# Issue with vs code not loading vector library

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-code

I'm doing an online course to try and build a dungeon crawler using c++ in vs code, however when importing the vector library it won't let me use any of the vector commands or features, I've checked my compiler set up and everything seems okay and can't for the life of me find out what's wrong.

```
#include <vector>
#include "Item.h"
#include "GameCharacter.h"

#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

using namespace std;

class Room
{
public:
    int pos;
    bool isExit;
    vector<Item> items;
    vector<GameCharacter> enemies;
    Room(int, bool, vector<Item>, vector<GameCharacter>);
    void clearLoot();
    void clearEnemies();
};

#endif
```

intellisense doesn't seem to pick it up at all, but the rest of the code seems fine.

running vs code on windows with mingw

Comment: does removing `using namespace std;` and specifying `std::vector` change intellisense?

Comment: With no OS or compiler information, it's hard to help. If I'm guessing Windows and MinGW, you likely didn't add everything to your PATH that you're supposed to.

Comment: doesn't appear to have changed it, command still hasn't changed colour or has been picked up by intellisense

Comment: doesn't seem to be anything in my compiler options, have another project folder with the same setup and the vector functions work absolutely fine, even when using `using namespace std;`

Comment: @D.Richardson Intellisense is just a tool -- it isn't a C++ compiler.  That tool can have bugs just like any other third-party tool.  The thing you shouldn't do is to attempt to change your code to make Intellisense "happy".  If you know the code is correct, well-written, etc.  a red squiggly line shouldn't be a deciding factor on making code changes.

Comment: IntelliSense is an attention-seeking approximation of a compiler. I usually switch it off.